# clone project from one repository to other

Tags: git

i have a folder with two git-repository, say "rcr-internals" and "prv.project.repository.bare".

I have to move (copy) only one project from one repository to other.

With other words - "prv.project.repository.bare/project_1" have to be copied to "rcr-internals/project_1".

At last i need to have the change history in "rcr-internals"-repository

i have tried to do the following:

```js
admin@linux:~/git/rcr-internals> git clone file://..prv.project.repository.bare/project_1/
```

but it doesn't work

is it possible to do it and how to do it?

thank for assistance

Answer (score 2):

you don't have to clone repository prv.project.repository.bare to copy folder.
You may add repository as a remote and then checkout project_1 from required branch.
Something like below:

```
git remote add prv <url of prv.project.repository.bare>
git fetch prv
git checkout prv/<branch_name> -- project_1
```

Comment: hmm. I have successful connected to remote repository, checked out the project and incorporate it in other project. I did make exactly the three steps from above. But late i found there is no history at all for the checked project. What was wrong? I would like to use smth like "git fetch --rebase prv" , but i am not sure

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add the remote(s) to your project.
Once you have added the remotes you can do what you want with it

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes#Adding-Remote-Repositories

---

#### What can you do?

- Clone the original repo
- Add new remote `git remote add <origin2> <url2>`
- Use the code from both the repositories inside a single repo

Now you can pull and merge the branches from the 2 remotes and have the code of both of them in a single repository.

As you can see in the image below you will have 2 repositories  which builds up your big repository.

```
# clone first repository
git clone <repo1>

# add remote 
git remote add <remote2> <url2>

# fetch all your data from all the remotes
git fetch --all --prune

# list of all the remotes
git remote -v
```

---

[image]

Comment: thank you. the call "git pull --rebase prv master" solved the issue with history